# Calculate median or mean depending on the value of a column

Tags: r, mean, median

I'm trying to calculate the median or mean depending on the value of a column.

Imagine the following DF

```
DF <- data.frame("name", 1:20, 3, 2:5, 0, 8:12)
colnames(DF)<- c("name","sample_1","sample_2", "sample_3", "median_mean", "Frequence")
```

I want to fill the "median_mean" column with the median or the mean of the 3 samples per row, depending on the frequency column. If Freq is bigger or equal to 10, use median, else, use mean.

Bear in mind that the sample won´t always be 3, so I can´t use columns (2:4). But they names will always be sample_X.

Any one could give me a hand?

Comment: What have you tried? Are you familiar with `if` statements? From what you've shared, it's not clear what level of help you need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
DF <- data.frame("name", 1:20, 3, 2:5, 0, 8:12)
colnames(DF)<- c("name","sample_1","sample_2", "sample_3", "median_mean", "Frequence")

DF$median_mean = ifelse(DF$Frequence>=10, apply(DF[grep("sample_", names(DF))], 1L, median), apply(DF[grep("sample_", names(DF))], 1L, mean))
```

---

### Explanation

We apply both `median` and `mean` to the relevant columns using:

- `apply(DF[grep("sample_", names(DF))], 1L, median)`

and

- `apply(DF[grep("sample_", names(DF))], 1L, mean)`

but we return only the value we want using the vectorized form of the ternary operator, `ifelse`.

The code also works for any number of columns named `sample_X` because we generalized the selection of columns simply searching their names with `grep("sample_", names(DF))`.

Comment: Thanks!! A few of the answer worked perfectly, but I´ll use this one as its organized in one vector!

Comment: @JM_44 Glad it helped you! Please, consider marking this answer as "accepted" (the green check mark under the score), so it counts as answered in the site.

Comment: I just did, I didn´t have unlocked that privilege until now ;)

Comment: @zx8754 Thanks for the edit, but I had it rolled back because OP accepted it in the first place for it being an one-liner, in spite possible performance considerations, which your edit improved upon.

Comment: No problem, your post you decide.

Answer (score 1):

Loop through rows, get matching function (*match.fun*) based on column *Frequence*:

```
# sample_ column index
ix <- grepl("sample_", colnames(DF), fixed = TRUE)

DF$median_mean <- apply(DF, 1, function(i){
  myFun <- match.fun(ifelse(i[6] >= 10, "median", "mean"))
  myFun(as.numeric(i[ix]))
})
```

Answer (score 0):

This works, use grep to get cols number

```
for(i in 1:nrow(DF)){

   cols <- grep("sample", names(DF))
   if(DF[i,]$Frequence > 10){
     DF$median_mean[i] <- mean(as.integer(DF[i,cols]))
   }else{
     DF$median_mean[i] <- median(as.integer(DF[i,cols]))
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DF <- data.frame("name", 1:20, 3, 2:5, 0, 8:12)
colnames(DF)<- c("name","sample_1","sample_2", "sample_3", "median_mean", "Frequence")

DF[DF$Frequence>10,]$median_mean<-apply(DF[DF$Frequence>10,grep("sample_",names(DF))],1,median)
DF[DF$Frequence<10,]$median_mean<-rowMeans(DF[DF$Frequence<10,grep("sample_",names(DF))])
```